# Error on calling a https endpoint on a server with self signed certificate

Tags: java, spring, rest, ssl, certificate

i'm writing a spring java microservice that calls some api deployed on a custom server that is already in production.

I try to call this api in my code, it is an https endpoint, and at the first try it returned me this error:

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

This is due the fact that the server has a self signed certificate.

I tried to get the certificate from the remote server with this command:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect hostname:443
```

and saved it in a file called root.crt.

Then i added this certificate to trusted certificate in my jvm with this command:

```
sudo keytool -importcert -keystore $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -file root.crt -alias "server_remote-root"
```

But now my application returns this error:

```
threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "$endpoint": No subject alternative names present] with root cause

java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
at java.base/sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchIP(HostnameChecker.java:142) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:101) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:452) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:426) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:238) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:638) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:473) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:369) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:458) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:201) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1506) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1421) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:455) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:426) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:580) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:187) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:142) ~[na:na]
```

Please help me!
Thank you!

I expect to reach the endpoint in the correct way.